# How to get row count in file using Azure Lookup Activity

Tags: lookup, azure-data-factory

I am reading the data file and RecordCount file having counts of record in data file. I am using lookup Activity to get the counts in data file and comparing it with the count of RecordCount file. This approach is working well and I can compare the records when we have count less than 5000. When data file has Count is more than 5000, it's considering only 5000 records and my pipeline is aborting because of count mismatch.
eg:

```
Datafile count: 7500

RecordCount file: 7500
```

Though counts are equal but Lookup will consider only 5000 records and will give a mismatch.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: What is the data source?

Comment: I am using ADLS

Comment: Which generation?

Comment: ADLS Gen2 and file is comma separated

Comment: I would use either a Databricks notebook or an Azure Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pool or Synapse notebook to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Data Flow to your pipeline before the Lookup. Source = ADLS Gen2, Sink = ADLS Gen2. Add a Surrogate Key transformation, call the new column as "mycounter". Add an Aggregate transformation and call the new column as "rowcount" with a formula of max(mycounter). In the Sink, output just the "rowcount" column. You'll now have a new dataset that is just the row count from any file. You can consume that row count as a single-line Lookup activity in the pipeline directly after your data flow.